# CQ5 using fileuploaddialogbuton xtype

Tags: adobe, aem

Can anyone post an example of how to setup fileuploaddialogbutton widget in a dialog?

I'm assuming this can be done - From the docs:

*"The FileUploadDialogButton creates a button that opens a new dialog for uploading a file via the FileUploadField. Can be used inside edit dialogs where the upload must happen in a separate form in the new dialog."*

The only results my searches seem to return is the Widget API documentation which offer no examples.

I've tried various random configurations in my dialog but get the JS error:

```
TypeError: c.setSize is not a function
  c.setSize(cw || undefined, ch || undefined);
```

Note I'm not specifying any height or width in the config (documentation doesn't list them as options). Can anyone offer an example of how to configure this correctly (dialog.xml snippet would be great)?

Thanks in advance

**EDIT:**

Here is my dialog XML as it stands. It gives the error, but it's not the only version that causes this js error in the console, nor do I make any claims that this should work hence (due to the lack of documentation) me asking for an example.

```
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0"
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Dialog"
    height="{Long}700"
    xtype="dialog">
    <items
    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
    xtype="tabpanel">
    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
        <tab1
            jcr:primaryType="cq:Panel"
            title="Tab 1">
            <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                <name
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    fieldLabel="Enter name"
                    name="./theName"
                    xtype="textfield"/>
                <description
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    fieldLabel="Change description"
                    name="./changeDescription"
                    xtype="richtext"/>
                <files
                    jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                    collapsed="{Boolean}false"
                    collapsible="{Boolean}false"
                    title="Files"
                    xtype="dialogfieldset">
                    <items jcr:primaryType="cq:WidgetCollection">
                        <test
                            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                            fieldLabel="Test"
                            xtype="textfield"/>
                        <file-upload
                            jcr:primaryType="cq:Widget"
                            dialogTitle="the dialog title"
                            fieldLabel="the field label"
                            text="the text"
                            xtype="fileuploaddialogbutton"/>
                    </items>
                </files>
            </items>
        </tab1>
    </items>
</items>
```

Comment: Post the dialog structure of your component for which the given error is being thown.

Comment: XML added above @rakhi4110. I have a work around by using a form on the page to upload files, which isn't what the user wants, but will do for now.

Comment: have you considered using html5smartfile instead? There you can set useFlash=false and it will also provide a file upload field.

Comment: Have you referred to OOTB calendar component ? CRX path for the component is/libs/collab/calendar/components/calendar it does has a dialog box which has file upload and meets the requirement as you have mentioned. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks guys. @yashahuja even copying how it's used in calendar raises the same issue. Thomas - I'll take a look at smart file.

Comment: @scribe1010 Try using the calendar component instead of copying.